# Передать массив в функцию JS

Tags: javascript

Понятно, что вопрос слабенький и так себе, и решение не знать ну просто стыдно, но все же очень-очень нужна помощь.

Схема такая: в функции должно быть два аргумента - список и функция. Эту "дочернюю" функцию нужно применить ко всем элементам списка. Функция должна получить два аргумента: значение и индекс.

Додумалась только до вот этого кусочка кода. Хелп!

```js
var list = [100, 200, 300, 400];

function map(func, list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    func(list[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: все правильно, только `func(list[i], i);`

Comment: все верно сделала, только забыла func(list[i], i)

Comment: а как с помощью этой функции, например, развернуть массив, в общем, провести какую-то манипуляцию, чтоб функция на него как-то повлияла/поменяла его?

Comment: @ingridBelan в js не рекомендуют изменять объекты. Рекомендуют создавать новые на основе старых.

Comment: А чем не устраивает существующий метод `map`, можно же просто написать `list.map(func)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать так. Менять объект по которому ты итерируешь - не самая лучшая идея, поэтому лучше в локальной переменной всё сделать и вернуть как результат функции.
В качестве функции можешь передать что угодно, что будет применено к каждому элементу и записано в новый массив.

```js
var list = [100, 200, 300, 400];

function map(list, func) {
  var f = func || function(list) {};

  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.push(f(list[i], i));
  }

  return result;
}

function multi(item, index) {
  return item * index;
}

function sqr(item, index) {
  return item * item;
}

console.log(map(list, multi));
console.log(map(list, sqr));
```